# What is the difference between? And how can they be used?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and when I follow tutorials they used both ways, Now I am confused between them. Anyone can help, please.

First one

```
$model->related_model.
```

Second one

```
$model->related_model()
```

Comment: The first resolves the relationship, the second returns an object that can resolve the relationship.

Comment: So, What is the usage of each of them?

Comment: See my answer and you will understand the usage for each of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first way, you are acessing the relationship value (a model or a collection of models, depending on relationship type):

```
$company()->clients // returns a collection of your clients (hasMany relationship for example)
$company()->owner // returns the owner model (belongsTo relationship for example)
```

When you access it as a property, laravel will load the relationship automatically for you (or use the cached value if the relationship was already loaded before).

The second way, will return the relationship itself, a object that represents the relationship and the query needed to load it:

```
$company->clients(); // instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
```

You use the second way when you need to do some complex query with your relationship, otherwise, use the first one.

A sample of using the second way:

```
$company->clients()->where('country', 'BR')->count()
```

Note that this way requires you to end your chain with a `get()`, `first()`, or any other similar methods like the `count()` used on this example.

Comment: very nice example

Comment: for this first way, as long as I am accessing the model it means I have access to the related table and its attributes. e.g. `$company()->clients->first_name;`
Am I correct? 

if so, then even the second way can be used to access table attributes as well,
 isn't it? e.g. `$company()->clients()->first_name;`

Comment: `$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->roles()->attach($roleId);`

This is an example from the doc, and it does not end the query with helper methods. [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @MuaathAlhaddad because `attach` is a specific method defined on the `BelongsToMany` class from the `belongsToMany` relationship definition